# Blazor, how to pass event target to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, blazor, blazor-client-side

I'd like to ask:

In Blazor, how to pass event target (or this) to my JavaScript? 
The thing is I'm creating inputs with `@foreach` so there can be a number of them.

Here is how it looks like:

```
@foreach (Item in ItemsList)
        {
          <input 
              @onchange="ChangeColor" 
              value="@Item.Value">
}
```

I want to simple `onchange` trigger this function:

```
@code 

{
    async Task ChangeColor()
    {
        await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("changeColor");
    }
}
```

And eventually read the value in my JS:

```
function changeColor (el) {


   console.log(el);

}
```

I tried using @ref, however I'd like to get access to the input that triggers the function. Since there may by many of them, I don't want to hardcode it using @ref to each of them.

Comment: What should `console.log(el)` show?

Comment: @Vencovsky I hoped to get DOM elemenet  <input >

Comment: You said "I tried using @ref, however I'd like to get access to the input that triggers the function. Since there may by many of them, I don't want to hardcode it using @ref to each of them" but I think something is wrong, I just added an answer trying to explain why and also made the code for it to work. But if you want to `console.log(el)` to return de DOM element, you need to use `@ref`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments

> @Vencovsky I hoped to get DOM elemenet

And if you want to show in the console the DOM element, you need to pass `@ref` to the DOM element and pass that reference to javascript

But then you say in your question

> I tried using @ref, however I'd like to get access to the input that triggers the function. Since there may by many of them, I don't want to hardcode it using @ref to each of them.

So it's kind of confusing, because you need to use `@ref` but you say you don't want to use `@ref`, so what I think is happening is that you used `@ref` the wrong way and you think you don't need it, but actually you do.

Here is what you need

- A property to hold all the refs of each element (`ElementReference`)
- Pass to `ChangeColor` only the element that is clicked

Here is an example on how to do it

```
@for(var i = 0; i < ItemsList.Count(); i++)
{
    var ii = i;

    @* Passing only the ref that called @onchange *@
    <input @onchange="(() => ChangeColor(Refs[ii]))" 
           @ref="Refs[ii]"
           value="@ItemsList[ii]">
}

@code 
{
    [Inject]
    IJSRuntime JSRuntime  { get; set; }

    async Task ChangeColor(ElementReference el)
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("changeColor", el);
    }

    // Property that will hold the refs 
    ElementReference[] Refs { get; set; }

    string[] ItemsList { get; set; } = new string[]
        {
            "hey",
            "hope",
            "this",
            "works"
        };
}
```